# Piping grep result to awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would to delete column from csv files containing some text as the column header.

I would like that the output_file be the same name as the file name found by the grep.

I did the following

```
grep -l "pattern" * | xargs -0 awk -F'\t' '{print $1"\t"$2}' > output_file
```

How to output the result to the same file found by the grep ?

Thank you.

Comment: You might be wanting to use `grep -l … | xargs awk …`, but `awk` doesn't have an option to overwrite the files it modifies, AFAIK. I've got a script `ow` (for 'overwrite') that I filched from 'The UNIX Programming Environment' many years ago that could be used.  If you've got GNU `sed`, you might be able to use that as it does have an overwrite option (or Mac OS X or BSD `sed` too).  Printing two tab separated columns (out of possibly many) is not too taxing for `sed` (though it is not entirely trivial either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this :

```
grep -l "pattern" * | xargs awk -F'\t' '{print $1"\t"$2 > FILENAME}'
```

FILENAME is the awk variable for your input file

Example :

```
$ cat file1
ABC zzz
EFG xxx
HIJ yyy
$ cat file2
123 aaa
456 bbb
789 ccc

grep -l "123" * | xargs awk '{print $2"\t"$1 > FILENAME}'
```

I switch columns 1 and 2 in the file containing "123" and overwrite file2.

```
$ cat file1
ABC zzz
EFG xxx
HIJ yyy
$ cat file2
aaa    123
bbb    456
ccc    789
```